# Creating Function for PHP Query to use at multiple locations

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a country, state, city cascading dropdown which I used in add property and edit property pages. The country table has columns : country_id and country_name.

Now when I want to load values into the edit page, I want to convert the country_id into country_name to show in the dropdown.  I am already able to do this using the following code:

```
<?php   
$country_id = $data['property_country'];
$select = $con->prepare("SELECT country_name from tbl_country where country_id='$country_id'");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$data2 = $select->fetchAll();
foreach ($data2 as $row1) {
    echo $row1['country_name'];
}
?>
```

However since this function will be used at multiple location I would like to make a function or a class and call it.  Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give us more information on how your program is structured but anyway as a general approach is to create a Country class
and make a method getCountries  where you can put your code without the loop,.

when you need the data, import the class file, instantiate the class passing the country_id and call the method.

Comment: Program is structured in core.  So I have a folder classes in which I can put the file, and call into the view file.

Comment: ` class Country {  
protected $id;
function __construct($id){
$this->id=$id;
}
getCountries(){
paste your code and pass $this->id as parameter
}

}

Answer (score 0):

Provide a more about question like how your data will go and how your answer goes like.

Create a class first and on calling page add require_once 'className.php'.

```
class A {

function __construct() {

}

function __destruct() {

}

public function countryIdToName($data, $con = null) {
    //Create you connection here or just pass connection link
    $country_id = $data['property_country'];
    $select = $con->prepare("SELECT country_name from tbl_country where country_id='$country_id'");
    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select->execute();
    $data2 = $select->fetchAll();
    foreach ($data2 as $row1) {
        echo $row1['country_name'];
    }
}

}
```

Now on your calling file lets take file name is **abc.php**

```
require_once 'A.php';
$classObject = new A();
$classObject->countryIdToName($data,$conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

`class Country {

         protected $id;
         function __construct($id){
             $this->id=$id;
         }
         function getCountries(){
              paste your code and pass $this->id as parameter and return $data
         }
    }`

now in your view 
import the class on top of of your view;

        `$countries = new Country(pass_the_id);
        $list = $countries->getCountries();`
end then your loop follows.